# If Statement Syntax Error on Passed Parameter

Tags: python

I am getting a Syntax Error on the `If` statement in the following code:

```
def ABC(faze):
    If faze == "d":
        print("Got a 'd'")
    Else:
        print("Didn't get a 'd'")

def XYZ():
    ABC("d")

XYZ()
```

The `faze` parameter in the `If` statement is highlighted when the error is thrown.  I've read other `If` statement syntax questions & answers here and none address my problem.  Why is the error happening?

Comment: Python is case sensitive. If you read other answers, you'd see your case doesn't match

Comment: I don't understand.  A lower-case 'd' is being passed and that's what's being checked.

Comment: Please read the answers. The string is not case sensitive, the python syntax is

Answer (score 1):

That's because Python has no `If` statements, only `if` statements. Capitalization matters. (Similarly, `Else` should be `else`.)

The error occurs because it's reading `If` as the name of a variable, immediately followed by another variable (`faze`), which makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

The if-else keywords should be of small case.

Comment: Who would have thunk it?  Thanks.